# How can I get only data that has been modified in Firebase using addChildEventListener?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofencing

I believe the problem is with my Query, because I try to Query but it always returns all the data in Firebase. I would just like the data that is marked yellow, which in this case would be just the data that has been modified.

It might help to ask: AreaRisco is a static key, but Brazil, Sao Paulo, Itaim Bibi and id are variable keys, I just want to get the key that was modified;

MyQuery:

```
queryAreaRisco = firebaseDatabase.getReference("AreaRisco").orderByKey().limitToLast(1);
```

My ChildEventListener:

```
 private void lerAreasRisco() {

    final ArrayList<Geofence> finalGeofences = new ArrayList<>();

    queryAreaRisco.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            Log.i ("GEOFENCE/TESTE", "adicionou um filho");


        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {


            Log.i ("GEOFENCE/TESTE", "mudou um filho - "+ results);
            Log.i ("GEOFENCE/TESTE-refs", String.valueOf(dataSnapshot));


            finalGeofences.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot areasRisco : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Log.i("GEOFENCE/TESTE - AREASR", areasRisco.getKey());
                if (!dataSnapshot.hasChildren()){
                    return;
                }


                for (DataSnapshot pais: areasRisco.getChildren()){
                    if (!pais.hasChildren()){
                        return;
                    }
                    Log.i("GEOFENCE/TESTE - CIDADE", pais.getKey());
                    Log.i ("GEOFENCE/TESTE", String.valueOf(pais.getRef()));
                    for (DataSnapshot cidade: pais.getChildren()){
                        if (!cidade.hasChildren()){
                            return;
                        }
                        Log.i ("GEOFENCE/TESTE", String.valueOf(cidade.getRef()));
                        chaveOcorrencia = cidade.getKey();
                        Centro_lat = (Double) cidade.child("Centro_lat").getValue();
                        Centro_lng = (Double) cidade.child("Centro_lng").getValue();
                        tipo = (String) cidade.child("Tipo").getValue();
                        Log.i("AREARISCO", String.valueOf(cidade));
                        Status = (Boolean) cidade.child("Status").getValue();
                        numero_Ocorrencia = (Long) cidade.child("numero_Ocorrencia").getValue();
                        pontoMaisDistanteLat = (Double) cidade.child("pontoMaisDistanteLat").getValue();
                        pontoMaisDistanteLng = (Double) cidade.child("pontoMaisDistanteLng").getValue();
                        if (!Status) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        ArrayList<Ocurrency> ocorrencias = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (DataSnapshot Ocorrencias : cidade.child("OcorrenciadaArea").getChildren()){
                            Ocurrency ocurrency = Ocorrencias.getValue(Ocurrency.class);
                            ocorrencias.add(ocurrency);
                        }
                        AreaRisco areaRisco = new AreaRisco();
                        areaRisco.setCentro_lat(Centro_lat);
                        areaRisco.setCentro_lng(Centro_lng);
                        areaRisco.setOcorrenciadaArea(ocorrencias);
                        areaRisco.setTipo(tipo);
                        areaRisco.setNumero_Ocorrencia(numero_Ocorrencia);
                        areaRisco.setPontoMaisDistanteLng(pontoMaisDistanteLng);
                        areaRisco.setPontoMaisDistanteLat(pontoMaisDistanteLat);
                        areaRisco.setStatus(Status);
                        finalGeofences.add(
                                new Geofence.Builder()
                                        .setRequestId(String.valueOf(chaveOcorrencia))
                                        .setCircularRegion(areaRisco.getCentro_lat(),
                                                areaRisco.getCentro_lng(),
                                                50)
                                        .setExpirationDuration(5000)
                                        .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER |
                                                Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
                                        .build()
                        );


                        Log.i("GEOFENCE/TESTE", "geofence adicionado para notificação");
                        Log.i("GEOFENCE/TESTE", chaveOcorrencia);
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O && Status) {
                            createAreaRisco(areaRisco, mMap);
                        }


                    }
                }
                break;
            }
            addGeofences(getGeofencingRequest(finalGeofences), getGeofencePendingIntent());
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.i ("GEOFENCE/TESTE", "removeu um filho");
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not nest this much in the firebase database. You can read this document to understand how to create the structure:

https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html

This line of code:

```
queryAreaRisco = firebaseDatabase.getReference("AreaRisco").orderByKey().limitToLast(1);
```

will retrieve the last key under `AreaRisco`, so if you have:

```
AreaRisco
    Brasil
       SaoPaolo
           Itaim bibi
              id
           Jardim Regina
              id
    France
      Paris
        Paris Bibi
             id
        Paris regina
             id
```

With the code above since you used `limitToLast(1)` it will return all the data under `France`. You need to change the structure to the following:

```
AreaRisco
  Itaim bibi
     randomid
         name : brasil
  Jardim Regina
     randomid1
          name : brasil
```

Then your query above will work and will give you the latest id.